# WP7 Passing data between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The basic navigation functionality of my app consists of selecting an item from a listbox, determine what item was selected and get its `id` value. Pass the `id` value to the next page and add it to an api url for use in a webclient to pull down new data. Here's what I have now.

Determine item selected and navigate to secondary page.

```
    public void genreSelectedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResultGenre data = (sender as TextBlock).DataContext as ResultGenre;
        ListBoxItem pressedItem = this.listGenres.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as ListBoxItem;
        if (pressedItem != null)
        {
            string genreID = "http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/beatport/genre?id=" + data.id;

            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/GenrePage.xaml?genreID=" + genreID, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

On the secondary page i can use OnNavigatedTo to get the url from the previous page, but the part i'm stuck on is plugging that url into the webclient.

```
    public GenrePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // WebClient jsonRelease
        WebClient jsonGenres = new WebClient();
        Uri apiGenre = new Uri("URL from previous page goes here");
        jsonGenres.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(jsonGenres_GetDataCompleted);
        jsonGenres.DownloadStringAsync(apiGenre);

    }

    // Textblock data from main page
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string genreID = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("genreID", out genreID))

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

Seems like the only thing i can do is add the url to an existing control on the secondary page. Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I've read a little bit on MVVM framework. Would that be a better way to handle this? If so how would that work? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this part of the Uri `"http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/beatport/genre?id="` ever change? If it doesn't, instead of passing the whole thing to `GenrePage` consider only passing `data.id` in the query string. Then create the Uri on the destination page.

If you must do it the way you've shown in your snippet, do the following:

```
string genreID = @"http://api.beatport.com/catalog/3/beatport/genre?id=" + data.id;
this.NavigationService.Navigate( new Uri( "/Pages/GenrePage.xaml?genreID=" + 
  Uri.EscapeDataString( genreID ), UriKind.Relative ) );
```

In GenrePage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GenrePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
  public GenrePage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
  {
    base.OnNavigatedTo( e );

    string genreID = String.Empty;
    if( NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue( "genreID", out genreID ) ) {
      LaunchWebClient( genreID );
    }
  }

  private void LaunchWebClient( string genreID )
  {
    WebClient jsonGenres = new WebClient();
    Uri apiGenre = new Uri( genreID );

    jsonGenres.DownloadStringCompleted += new 
      DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler( jsonGenres_GetDataCompleted );
    jsonGenres.DownloadStringAsync( apiGenre );
  }
}
```

[Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) will insert the appropriate escape characters into the query string. The query string is automatically unescaped on the destination page, so you don't need to do anything special there.